# Vega lite Geographic chart: does zoom on mouse scroll feature exist?

Tags: vega-lite

I am using this map https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/geo_layer.html and I'm wondering if there is a zoom function in principle here? Found nothing in docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can zoom the map manually by changing the scale factor of the projection as below. To actually bind this to mouse scroll is not currently supported as far as I'm aware. There is an open issue here you can rad about: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/3306

If I were you, I'd just use Vega and there is already an example here: https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/zoomable-world-map/

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 500,
  "height": 300,

  "layer": [
    {
      "data": {
        "url": "data/us-10m.json",
        "format": {
          "type": "topojson",
          "feature": "states"
        }
      },
      "projection": {
        "type": "albersUsa", "scale":300
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "geoshape",
        "fill": "lightgray",
        "stroke": "white"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "url": "data/airports.csv"
      },
      "projection": {
        "type": "albersUsa", "scale":300
      },
      "mark": "circle",
      "encoding": {
        "longitude": {
          "field": "longitude",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "latitude": {
          "field": "latitude",
          "type": "quantitative"
        },
        "size": {"value": 10},
        "color": {"value": "steelblue"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: David, is there a way to create same Vega but not for the whole world but only for USA https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/zoomable-world-map/ ?

Comment: Yes, just change the topojson and the projection and it should work.

Comment: David, could you take a look please, i've updated my initial post here with the data...

Comment: Can you rollback your edit and ask a new question as the new question is about Vega and not Vega-Lite. It helps to keep the questions focused on one thing